# Removing field from json and casting it to jsonb

Tags: postgresql

I want to remove field from array of jsons and then retreive that array as jsonb object. I am able to remove field. Now I want to have single object to return from function.

The way it is now I get

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

```
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        WITH records (game_numbers) AS (
            SELECT *
            FROM jsonb_array_elements($1))

       SELECT (game_numbers - 'code')::json
        FROM records);

END;
$$;
```

I have data like:

```
"game_numbers":[
                  {
                    "id":1,
                    "code":"code1"
                  },
                  {
                    "id":2,
                    "code": "code2"
                  }

               ]
```

I want to receive:

```
"game_numbers":[
                  {
                    "id":1,
                  },
                  {
                    "id":2,
                  }

               ]
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: I've added basic example, the result I have is exception at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the function to return a jsonb, then you need to aggregate the elements back to a jsonb.

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION fnRemoveCodeElement(jsonb)
> RETURNS jsonb AS $$
>     SELECT json_agg(value - 'code')::jsonb
>     FROM jsonb_array_elements($1)
> $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT fnRemoveCodeElement('[
> {
>   "id":1,
>   "code":"code1"
> },
> {
>   "id":2,
>   "code": "code2"
> }
> ]') js
> ```

> | js |
> | --- |
> | [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}] |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e780b0ed8e1620828a2fd7027a412e37)*